# Regex case insensitive match of list of words with word boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the string:

`This is a test, and all test-alike words should be testtest and checked.`

I would like to write RegEx that will match either `test` or `test-alike` infinite amount of time but not `testtest`.

I'm no regex expert I have come up with the following so far.

`\s*(\btest-alike\b|\btest\b)` matches well but when doing something like test-test it will match and it shouldn't.
`(^|[^\w])(\btest\b|\btest-alike\b)($|[^\w])` this one matches correctly using capture groups but its every alternate match so match no-match match etc.

Would like to know if for first regex there is a way to specify the condition to not match when words are split by chars like ' ' '' '"' etc.

Comment: To understand your problem better, could you clarify: 1) do you have a big list of words to search for? 2) do you build the regex pattern dynamically? 3) Can the search words/phrases start or end with special chars? I feel that word boundaries are not a solution, you can probably replace them with whitespace boundaries here, `(?<!\S)` at the start and `(?!\S)` at the end.

Comment: 1. It should not exceed 100 words.
2. Yes preferably the middle capture group should be built dynamically
3. Words only should not start nor end with special chars

Comment: Well, 100 words is already a lot if you consider the backtracking impact if all of them start with the same prefix. Ok, what about the rest?

Comment: In theory, I would like to build a highlighter based on keyword list and text input. So I figured out the best way to do it is to use regex to match words and count them that way. AFAIK there is not evading parsing the whole text in such a case.

Comment: Then please take a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63849592/3832970). Is it answering your question? I think there might be only one change needed for a basic version, that is, escaping search terms. But if the search words have no special chars, escaping is not necessary. Actually, it is even a bit more advanced as that code supports different span classes for different search words to highlight.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry my bad I misinterpreted your question the derivate word list should not exceed let's say 5. But regex would run for many words and derivatives in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one might help ... [`/\b(?:\w+-)*test(?:-\w+)*\b/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/gU6I1U/1).

It tries matching the word that is searched for altogether with both optional leading and trailing valid character sequences with each sequence build by at least one word character and a connecting `-` (`(?:\w+-)*` or other way around `(?:-\w+)*`) ...

```js
const sampleText = `This is a Test, and all alike-alike-test-alike-alike words should be testtest and checked.

This is a test-Test, and all alike-alike-Test alike-alike words should be testtest and checked.`;

const regX = (/\b(?:\w+-)*test(?:-\w+)*\b/gi);
const search = 'test';

console.log(
  sampleText.match(regX)
);
console.log(
  sampleText.match(
    RegExp(`\\b(?:\\w+-)*${ search }(?:-\\w+)*\\b`, 'gi')
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

Regarding the subject that was furthermore discussed within several comment blocks, a search and replace/highlight approach might look like this ...

```js
function toRegExpSearch(str) {
  return String(str)
    .replace((/[$^*+?!:=.|(){}[\]\\]/g), (([match]) => `\\${ match }`))
    .replace((/\s+/g), '\\s+');
}
function highlightSearch(text, search) {
  const regX = RegExp(`\\b((?:\\w+-)*${ toRegExpSearch(search) }(?:-\\w+)*)\\b`, 'gi');

  const matchList = text.match(regX) || [];
  return text
    .split(regX)
    .reduce((str, partial) => {
      if (partial === matchList[0]) {
        matchList.shift();

        str = `${ str }<mark>${ partial }</mark>`;
      } else {
        str = `${ str }${ partial }`;
      }
      return str;
    }, '');
}
const sampleText = `This is a Test, and all alike-alike-test-alike-alike words should be testtest and checked.

This is a test-Test, and all alike-alike-Test alike-alike words should be testtest and checked.`;


console.log(
  highlightSearch(sampleText, 'TEST')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\btest(-[a-zA-A]*)?\b/gi
```

here \btest will match the test and (-[a-zA-Z]*)?\b will check for word after '-'.

Answer (score 0):

As per Wiktor's answer above. The solution to this problem is:

`\b(?:test-alike|test's)\b`

Please note that words should be sorted. Detailed info can be found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63849493/javascript-regexp-to-apply-span-tags-on-strings-with-nested-substrings/63849592#63849592).